# How do I update an Object inside an array inside another object with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I have the following structure

```json
{
   "serverId": serverId,
   "name": serverName,
   "members":[
      {
         "birthday":{
            "$date":{
               "$numberLong":birthDate
            }
         },
         "user": userName,
      },
      {
         "birthday":{
            "$date":{
               "$numberLong":birthDate2
            }
         },
         "user": userName2,
      }
   ]
   }
}
```

I'm not sure how to use Mongoose to update the birthday of one of the members.

I have two models for the Objects that i'm storing:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const memberSchema = Schema({
    birthday: {
        default: '',
        type: Date,
    },
    user: {
        default: '',
        type: String,
    },
})

module.exports = model('Member', memberSchema, 'memberTest')
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const serverSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    serverId: {
        default: '1',
        type: String,
    },
    name: {
        default: 'emptyServer',
        type: String,
    },
    members: [],
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Server', serverSchema, 'servers')
```

I've tried doing this:

```js
        const newBirthday = new Member({
            user: message.author.tag,
            birthday: date
        })
        let dbMember = dbServer.members.filter(member => member.user = message.author.tag)

        if(dbMember){
            dbServer.update({'members.user': message.author.tag}, {'$set': {
                'members.$.user': message.author.tag,
                'members.$.birthday': date
            }})
        }else{
            dbServer.members.push(newBirthday)
        }

        dbServer.save()
```

but it doesn't update the members on the DB.

After I tested this, I could see the update on the object (by logging it) but when I look into de DB the changes are not there. I'm not entirely sure if what I'm doing is really off tracks

Comment: I'm not sure, but see if you can just directly update the member itself: `const member = dbServer.members.find(m => m.user === message.author.tag); member.birthday = date; member.save()`

Comment: Nope, member doesn't have a save function()

Comment: If you change your schema like in the example [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), I think then it may work. In that case, the `members: []` would be an array of references to `Member` instances.